# Error while downloading source code of android

Tags: android, download, operating-system, repo, fedora-25

I am using fedora 25, and using the following commands to download android gingerbread.

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-2.3.7_r1
repo sync -c -j4
```

After typing it (after almost 24hours, download of size 13G),

I get:

```
Fetching projects:  97% (166/171)  Fetching project platform/external/neven
Fetching project platform/external/dnsmasq
Fetching projects:  99% (170/171)  remote: Sending approximately 2.15 GiB ...        
remote: Counting objects: 367, done        
remote: Finding sources: 100% (2029012/2029012)           
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
remote: Sending approximately 2.15 GiB ...        
remote: Counting objects: 367, done        
remote: Finding sources: 100% (2029012/2029012)           
^Cerror: Cannot fetch platform/frameworks/base MiB | 118.00 KiB/s   
aborted by user
```

That error keeps repeating. I read about it on the internet and it says, that I need to generate RSA keys and then copy that to GitHub account. How am I supposed to do that.

Also please explain the meaning of those errors especially

```
remote: Sending approximately 2.15 GiB ...
```

Is it downloading or uploading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it.
This is not a technical solution, but the thing that i did different from past three-four attempts is that I kept the system active(not in sleep mode, as it goes off after a certain period of idle interaction) at

> Receiving objects:  99% (2024331/2029012), 2.10 GiB | 119.00 KiB/s

At 98 or 99 percent download make sure that os doesn't go sleep mode.[image]